# Remove vertical spacing between AlertDialog content and actions

Tags: flutter

I have the following custom dialog:

```
class MyDialog extends AlertDialog {
  MyDialog(BuildContext context) :
    super(
      content: Wrap(
        children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed malesuada ligula metus, eleifend condimentum nibh maximus a. Curabitur a ligula massa."),
              CheckboxListTile(
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  value: false,
                  title: Text("Don't show again"),
                  controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                  onChanged: (val) {}
              )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
      actions: [
        FlatButton(
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
          child: Text('OK')
        )
      ],
    ) {}
}
```

My issue is the the alert dialog seems to have too much vertical spacing between the content and the actions (due to the whitespace on the side of the checkbox tile). Is there a way to remove that vertical spacing?:

[image: Alert Dialog]

Comment: Why are you subclassing AlertDialog, instead of just composing it?

Comment: construct your own with plain `Dialog` Widget rather  than `AlertDialog`

Answer (score 3):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `contentPadding`, `buttonPadding` and `actionsPadding`
`actionsPadding` default value is `EdgeInsets.zero` 
code snippet

```
MyDialog(BuildContext context)
      : super(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          buttonPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          content: Wrap(
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyDialog extends AlertDialog {
  MyDialog(BuildContext context)
      : super(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          buttonPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          content: Wrap(
            children: [
              Column(
                children: [
                  Text(
                      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed malesuada ligula metus, eleifend condimentum nibh maximus a. Curabitur a ligula massa."),
                  CheckboxListTile(
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      value: false,
                      title: Text("Don't show again"),
                      controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                      onChanged: (val) {})
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
          actions: [
            FlatButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(), child: Text('OK'))
          ],
        ) {}
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            MyDialog(context),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```